# induction triangle question prove x triangles are formed

Tags: induction

Prove with induction: Given n non parallel lines such that no three intersect at a point, there are c(n,3) triangles formed.

so I have n!/(n-3)!3! triangles if this condition holds, that is all I understand how to do from this question

Answer (score 1):

The non-inductive proof is that you can choose any three lines and they will form a triangle.

The inductive proof is to start with the base case:  with three lines you get one triangle.  Now assume it is true for $k$ lines, so there are $C(k,3)$ triangles .  Add another line.  It will form $\frac 12 k(k-1)$ new triangles.  Add these in and show that this gives a total of $C(k+1,3)$

Comment: Hm..why does adding one extra line to k lines form $1/2k (k+1)$ lines?  I thought of a strong induction proof but this seems better.

Comment: Because you add a triangle for each pair of existing lines.  That feels a bit like the non-inductive proof to me, though.

Comment: Are you sure the number of new triangles formed depends on the number of lines? I think it depends on how many _new triangles_ $k$ lines form. If the number of new triangles $k$ lines form is $x$, then the number of triangles formed by $k+1$ lines is $1/2x(x+1)$. Am I mistaken? I apologize if I am.

Comment: Each new line will cross all the previous lines.  It will therefore make a new triangle with each pair of existing lines.  But I just realized that the plus sign should be a minus, because from $k$ lines one can form $\frac 12k(k-1)$ pairs.  Incidentally, please write it as $k(k+1)/2$ or $(1/2)k(k+1)$ or use \frac to stack the fraction.  With the slash it is not clear what is in the denominator.  We get various things on this site.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense now! Because $\frac 12 k(k+1)$ is the $k^{th}$ triangular number, I got confused. The triangular numbers actually represent how many new triangles are formed, don't they? And, I will from now on, thank you so much.

Comment: The triangular numbers are named that for a different reason-if you make a triangle with $1,2,3,4,\dots,k$ items, they are the number of items.  They show up often in combinatoric problems.  My original was a triangular number, too, just one notch too large.

Comment: why are we multiplying by 1/2?

Comment: When you count the triangles formed by line $k+1$, you get one for each pair of earlier lines.  You have $k$ choices for the first line and $k-1$ for the second.  But we get each pair twice this way, so have to divide by $2$.  This is exactly $C(k,2)$